Adding gamma values to raster band
I have a TIFF file and tested out that gamma 0.5 would be nice to add to the red band. How can I do this mathematically using gdal, would rather not use Python?
newRed = originalRed^gamma


Three alternatives came into my mind: use gdalenhance, use an edited VRT file, or use gdal_translate by applying an exponential scale.
Alternative 1.
Create a LUT with for example Excel
in  in^0.5
0   0 
1   1
2   1.414213562
3   1.732050808
4   2
5   2.236067977
6   2.449489743
7   2.645751311
8   2.828427125
9   3
10  3.16227766
11  3.31662479
12  3.464101615
13  3.605551275
14  3.741657387
15  3.872983346
...

Read the documentation of gdalenhance https://gdal.org/en/latest/programs/gdalenhance.html and convert your LUT table into the format that gdalenhance is using:
1:Band -0.5:ScaleMin 255.5:ScaleMax 0 0 8 16 16 17 17 17 17 18 18 18 18 18 18 19 19 19 19 20 20 20...

Be the examples only integers are supported in the LUT file and with gamma=0.5 the file would begin as
1:Band -0.5:ScaleMin 255.5:ScaleMax 0 1 1 2 2 3 3 3...

Correct me if I am wrong, but I have never used gdalenhance myself.
Alternative 2.
Alternatively, you can write the LUT table into the GDAL VRT configuration file https://gdal.org/en/latest/drivers/raster/vrt.html.

The ComplexSource supports adding a custom lookup table to transform
the source values to the destination. The LUT can be specified using
the following form:
<LUT>[src value 1]:[dest value 1],[src value 2]:[dest value 2],...</LUT>


Alternative 3.
For applying a fixed exponent for the whole layer even this gdal_translate command might do the job:
gdal_translate -of VRT -scale 0 255 0 255 -exponent_1 0.5 -exponent_2 1.0 -exponent_3 1.0 source.tif with_gamma_corrected_red.tif

